# IIS7 Url Rewrite Rule Not Firing (For Script Src)

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I'm solving a web application issue we have with versioning non-embedded resources (scripts, for example) to force a reload despite any client cache.

Part of this solution involves using IIS Url Rewrite to take the script location (as specified by 'src') and rewrite it to the actual resource.  So, the we b page as served will have something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jsmenu/menu.js?ver=1.1"></script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jsmenu/menu-1_1.js"></script>
```

and the Rewrite Rule would take the corresponding client request and turn that into a request for:

```
"../jsmenu/menu.js"
```

I've installed the Rewrite module, and created a rule using the UI (which then appears in the web.config), done numerous IISresets, but nothing seems to happen.

Here is the rule:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="VersionScripts">
                <match url="../jsmenu/menu_([0-9]+)_([0-9]+).js" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="../jsmenu/menu.js" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

The url doesn't get rewritten, and the script doesn't load (because it's not actually called "menu_1_1.js").  If I look in the log (both with and without logRewrittenUrl = "true" ) I don't see anything to indicate that it fired.

What am I missing?

Bonus points if you can help rewrite the rule so that any relative path info is preserved (the rule works whether it's src="../../jsmenu/menu_1_1.js" or src="../jsmenu/menu_1_1.js" or whatever, and that path is preserved in the rewritten url).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that

```
src="../jsmenu/menu_1_1.js"
```

was actually becoming a

```
GET /jsmenu/menu_1_1.js
```

and that didn't match the pattern.

Changing the pattern to

```
url="(.*)menu_([0-9]+)_([0-9]+).js"
```

both made it match, and got me the path prefix I was looking for.